# JavaScript try...catch for defineProperty not working

Tags: javascript, try-catch, getter-setter, defineproperty

I'd like to know why the error is not raised inside the catch block when i use `Object.defineProperty()` method with `get()` and `set()`?

```js
    try {
      var f;
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', {
        get: function() {
          return fxxxxx; // here: undef var but no error catched
        },
        set: function(v) {
          f = v;
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('try...catch OK: ', e);
    }
    
    a = function() {
      return true;
    }
    window.a();

    // Expected output: "try...catch OK: ReferenceError: fxxxxx is not defined"
    // Console output: "ReferenceError: fxxxxx is not defined"
```

Comment: Thank you, Crowder. And very good answer.

Comment: In future, though, better to use Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to create runnable on-site demos rather than jsFiddle, which is off-site. (My answer has a snippet so you can see what they're like.)

Comment: I will do it it next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a `ReferenceError` to create a function that refers to a symbol that isn't unresolvable at the time the function is created. The error happens **later**, when the function is called, *if* the symbol is unresolvable at that time.

Consider, for instance, that you could do this:

```js
try {
  var f;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', {
    get: function() {
      return fxxxxx;
    },
    set: function(v) {
      f = v;
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('try...catch OK: ', e);
}

window.fxxxxx = function() { console.log("Hi there"); };   // <====== Added this

a = function() {
  return true;
}
window.a();
```

That logs `"Hi there"` because `fxxxxx` *isn't* unresolvable as of when the `get` function is called.

Comment: @Crowder, @Bergi: thank you for your explaintation. Also, try/catch does the same behavior with code that is inside the `addEventListener` when error happens later.

Comment: @poro6 Yes, it's the same for all function definitions. The exception is created when the function is called, not when it is created. Regardless whether that's a simple declaration, a getter (like in your question) or an event listener.

Comment: @Bergi: this is a golden rule for me. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Influencing from @T.J. Crowder's answer, if you would like to try to catch that error you should change your code as follows;

```js
var f;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', {
    get: function() {
      try {
      return fxxxxx; // here: undef var but no error catched
      }
      catch(e){console.log("i've got it", e)}
    },
    set: function(v) {
      f = v;
    }
  });

a = function() {
  return true;
}
window.a;
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will do it on this way.